# Addons tabs will disappear from the n-tab toolbar

Tags: interface

I have this persistent on going issue where I'll mindlessly hit a hotkey by accident and then all the addons I have installed will disappear in the n-tab menu before I even notice. The addons are still installed and are functional, but I can't access their tab menus as it just blips out of excistence every so often. The n-tab menu will only have the default tabs like tools, view, and edit.

Below I put a picture with the retopoflow, which has it's own menu and buttons at the top; this tells me the addons are working and installed. Sometimes, the tabs will reappear after hitting random hotkeys or will just be there when I reopen blender after a long time. Everytime I try googling this issue, there's no information on this it or I get redirected on how to install an addon or troubleshoot it. If I unistall, and reinstall the addons, it will come back onto the n-tab menu for a moment, but then disappear after working for a while or if I close out blender.

I had this problem with ver 2.8, 2.9 and now 3.6.1.

Is this some sort of bug, or is it a hotkey I'm not aware of?

[image]

Comment: I think that first you are somehow going to have to find out which key it is that you "mindlessly hit... by accident". Then in Edit->Preferences->Interface turn on Developer Extras. Then in Preferences->Add-ons activate the Development: Is key Free addon. Open the dropdown for it and click on the brief Documentation for how to use it. With it you can get a list of all the keys that are assigned in your Blender setup. You can copy and paste this list into some text program, e.g., Notepad on Windows and search for the key you think you pressed. Continued...

Comment: Note that the list can be long and that some keys are used in multiple places. You might be able to find the problem key this way.